# Logic App - Difference between Workflow/Runtime Outbound IP-addresses and Connector Outbound IP-addresses

Tags: ip, runtime, azure-logic-apps, connector, outbound

Can someone please explain to me the difference between the new way that Azure differs between the outbound IP-addresses for the logic apps please.

I think the documentation is so slimmed down in doing a proper explanation of that issue. Reading it it sounds like the IP-addresses have the exact same role in the logic app.

I just need a bit of clarity regarding this point.

So, whats the difference between Workflow/Runtime Outbound IP-addresses and Connector Outbound IP-addresses in a Logic App. [Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, So i have made some progress regarding this question and i think i understand what the difference is. The information that (in my opinion) wasn't clear to me regarding the difference between these two types of IP-addresses in the documentation, was what i'm about to explain in the following parts below.

So, the difference of usage between these two can be explained in how the IP-addresses are used by the logic app in regards to on-platform-resources, and external resources so to speak.

As I've come to understand it as such:

**"Connector Outbound Ip-Addresses"** 
- are used by for example, a trigger in your Logic App, that uses an "API-Connector" resource in your resource group or to call a Service Bus queue or something like an FTP.
So every connector/trigger/action that needs a "API-Connector" to make a connection/polling or call uses the "Connector Outbound Ip-Addresses".

**"Runtime Outbound Ip-Addresses"**
- are used in whenever the Logic app itself needs to call an external part NOT using a "API-Connector" resource. That would be for example a HTTP-Connector making a REST-call to an external API or system.

Please correct me if i'm wrong on this part and i will correct this post. As for now this is my understanding of the difference in usage between these two.

Comment: Good to keep in mind which was problem that we encountered with with the  "Connector Outbound Ip-Addresses" is - that all IP - addresses are not shown in the portal. even if one is shown in the properties for the logic app, doesn't mean that its the one being used. Microsoft has recognized this problem and said that they would fix this. Just open for the whole range given in the documentation to be sure, when white listing.

Answer (score 2):

Connectors today (e.g. SQL, FTP, Salesforce, CRM, whatever) all have static ip addresses per region. However the `HTTP` and `HTTP + Swagger` action will send events from a dynamic set of IP Addresses.

We have an item to fix this in the future, but for now best way is to make the call through a connector (including a custom connector) **so you can ensure a static IP**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so lets say i have an "http-connector" in my workflow in a logic app, that one wouldn't do the request through the "Connector outbound IP address"? hoe you understand my confusion here?  is the "connector IP" only for internal events and calls? i still don't understand what the exact difference between them is? thanks for taking the time to try and explain this :)